# How to create encrypted model in LTspice with .lib statement inside

Tags: ltspice

I created a device from schematic - asy file + sub file. I wanted to encrypt this device, so I used a command ltspice.exe -encrypt "file path". But LTspice return the error ".lib statements should not be in a 3rd party encrypted file". I do not know what to do, because I used operational amplifier (UniversalOpAmp2.lib) and diode (standard.dio) inside my device, so obviously .lib statement will be present in this sub file. Could someone please advice how to convert a device included a diode and OpAmp, i.e. .lib statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do to solve this would be to remove the `.lib`'s and manually copy/paste the .subckt for `level2` from `UniversalOpAmp2.lib` into the custom `.sub` file you want to encrypt. You can just paste the text at the end after the existing `.subckt` / `.ends` for your custom device. Do the same thing with the diode `.model`(s) you used from `standard.dio`.  Here is an example of what your `.sub` should look like before you attempt to encrypt it.

```
.subckt MyCustomDevice 1 2 3 4 5
...
...
...
.ends

.subckt level2 1 2 3 4 5
S1 5 3 X 5 Q
S2 4 5 5 X Q
A1 2 1 0 0 0 0 X 0 OTA G={Avol/Rout} ref={Vos} Iout={slew*Cout} Cout={Cout} en={en} enk={enk} in={in} ink={ink} incm={incm} incmk={incmk} Vhigh=1e308 Vlow=-1e308
C3 5 4 1p
C4 3 5 1p
R2 X 4 {2*Rout} noiseless
R1 3 X {2*Rout} noiseless
R3 3 1 {2*Rin} noiseless
R4 3 2 {2*Rin} noiseless
R5 2 4 {2*Rin} noiseless
R6 1 4 {2*Rin} noiseless
B1 X 0 I=if(V(x,3)<0,0,({2*slew*Cout}*V(x,3))**2)
B2 0 X I=if(V(x,4)>0,0,({2*slew*Cout}*V(4,x))**2)
D1 5 3 X
D2 4 5 X
.param Rout=100Meg
.param Cout={Avol/GBW/2/pi/Rout}
.model Q SW(Ron=10 Roff=10Meg Vt=0 Vh=-.1 Vser={Rail} ilimit={Ilimit} noiseless level=2 epsilon={Rail/10})
.param Avol=1Meg GBW=10Meg Slew=10Meg ilimit=25m rail=0 Vos=0
.param en=0 enk=0 in=0 ink=0 incm=0 incmk=0 Rin=1G
.model X D(Ron=1 epsilon=10 noiseless)
.ends level2

.model 1N4148 D(Is=2.52n Rs=.568 N=1.752 Cjo=4p M=.4 tt=20n Iave=200m Vpk=75 mfg=OnSemi type=silicon)

.model BAT54 D(Is=.1u Rs=2.2 N=1 Cjo=12p M=.3 Eg=.69 Xti=2 Iave=300m Vpk=30 mfg=Vishay type=Schottky)
```

---

You can alternatively include the extra models within the existing subcircuit definition, usually at the end (see below).  This might actually be safer, in case (for example) someone defines a `.model` 1N4148 in the top-level schematic which could conflict with the one defined within your `.sub`.  Doing it this way restricts scope/access to the `.model` within your custom subcircuit only.  Might be a good idea to label your `.ends` statement to avoid confusion when doing nested subcircuits like this.

```
.subckt MyCustomDevice 1 2 3 4 5
...
...
...
.subckt level2 1 2 3 4 5
S1 5 3 X 5 Q
S2 4 5 5 X Q
A1 2 1 0 0 0 0 X 0 OTA G={Avol/Rout} ref={Vos} Iout={slew*Cout} Cout={Cout} en={en} enk={enk} in={in} ink={ink} incm={incm} incmk={incmk} Vhigh=1e308 Vlow=-1e308
C3 5 4 1p
C4 3 5 1p
R2 X 4 {2*Rout} noiseless
R1 3 X {2*Rout} noiseless
R3 3 1 {2*Rin} noiseless
R4 3 2 {2*Rin} noiseless
R5 2 4 {2*Rin} noiseless
R6 1 4 {2*Rin} noiseless
B1 X 0 I=if(V(x,3)<0,0,({2*slew*Cout}*V(x,3))**2)
B2 0 X I=if(V(x,4)>0,0,({2*slew*Cout}*V(4,x))**2)
D1 5 3 X
D2 4 5 X
.param Rout=100Meg
.param Cout={Avol/GBW/2/pi/Rout}
.model Q SW(Ron=10 Roff=10Meg Vt=0 Vh=-.1 Vser={Rail} ilimit={Ilimit} noiseless level=2 epsilon={Rail/10})
.param Avol=1Meg GBW=10Meg Slew=10Meg ilimit=25m rail=0 Vos=0
.param en=0 enk=0 in=0 ink=0 incm=0 incmk=0 Rin=1G
.model X D(Ron=1 epsilon=10 noiseless)
.ends level2
.model 1N4148 D(Is=2.52n Rs=.568 N=1.752 Cjo=4p M=.4 tt=20n Iave=200m Vpk=75 mfg=OnSemi type=silicon)
.model BAT54 D(Is=.1u Rs=2.2 N=1 Cjo=12p M=.3 Eg=.69 Xti=2 Iave=300m Vpk=30 mfg=Vishay type=Schottky)
.ends MyCustomDevice
```